# Function which take a callback and return promise: is it bad?

Tags: javascript, callback, promise

I'm working on a kind of SDK. By design all of the async function should work with both: callbacks and promises. For example:

```
function asyncOp(arg, cb) {
...
}
asyncOp(1, (err, res) => { ... }) // returns undefined when you pass a callback
asyncOp(1).then(...) // returns a promise when callback is undefined
```

Is there anything bad in this kind of interface? Can you provide any examples of popular libraries which provide similar interface?

Comment: Kinda opinion based. I prefer 1 exact interface, so in my own projects I always use the `promisify()` function to turn callbacks into promises. But since turning a callback into a promise and vice versa can be coded in only a few lines I would opt to choose one or the other and let your SDK users decide for themselves if they want to cast what you decide to what they like.

Comment: If it is a new SDK I see no reason to support callback approach. The benefits of promises vs callbacks are well documented

Comment: agree with both of you. the problem here - you never work alone, and there can be  some colleague which thinks that supports both interfaces is better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB's node.js API does this for one.

As for "is there anything bad": it makes your library's code a bit harder to read. There's also something to be said for consistency and not supporting bad patterns, but that's opinion-based.